# Jquery e JSF - formatar máscaras para campos de textos

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

Boa noite, estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade e estou utilizando máscaras para campos decimais no meu campo de texto, onde tenho que validar com uma precisão de 4 casas demais no máximo, coloquei uma máscara com a precisão de 4, mas em vista do que foi pedido ele também deve aceitar preencher o campo com 1, 2, 3 casas decimais, tem alguma forma de usar colocando o mínimo e máximo de precisão nós campos mascarados.

```
<f:facet name=“header”>
<h:outputLabel value="#{messages.conversion}"/>
</f:facet>
<h:inputText id=“fldConversion” value="#{row.vlConversion}" label="#{messages.conversion}"
maxLength=“18” disabled="#{defaultMBean.canDisabledConversion(row)}">

<a4j:ajax event=“change” immediate=“true” render="@all, partnerItem, dataModel"/>
<f:converter converterId=“javax.faces.BigDecimal”/>
<f:validateLength maximum=“19” />
</h:outputText>
```

E coloquei assim no javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Configuração para campos de Real.
// Configuração para mudar a precisão da
máscara. Neste caso a máscara irá
// aceitar 4 dígitos após a virgula.
jQuery("#fldConversion").maskMoney({
showSymbol : false,
symbol : “false”,
decimal : “.”,
thousands : “.”,
precision : 4
});
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer essa máscara pegar uma precisão de 1 a 5 casas decimais na mascara, tipo um valor máximo e mínimo de casas decimais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo um pouco diferente do seu mais acho que é isso que quer, coloque assim em seu **javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#money').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse:true}); })
```

E no **HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="money" placeholder="Digite um valor"/>
```

Comment: Opa valeu funcionou, muito obrigado.

Comment: O bom que agora não fica igual antes ficava as vezes eu queria jogar 1 casa decimal do intervalo de 1 a 4, ele só jogava uma precisão de 4 casas agora eu posso jogar com 1 casa que ele aceita também.

Comment: Se resolveu o seu problema marque a resposta como resolvida "✅" ajuda os novos usuários do Stack Overflow.